# Наследование от библиотечных классов

Tags: java, наследование

В имеющейся библиотеке, от абстрактного класса образовано три новых не абстрактных класса потомка. Нужно в потомках добавить общие поля и методы. Не хочется исправлять родительский класс прямо в библиотеке. Можно-ли, не меняя эти библиотечные классы, создать новые, чтобы не дублируя, добавить общие поля и методы в новых классах?
Библиотека чужая. Если ее обновят - придется вносить свои изменения.  Рассмотрев все предложения, я принял решение внести изменения в библиотеке,  добавив свой функционал.

Comment: унаследуйтесь от потомков и добавьте новые поля

Comment: С какой целью вы расширяете библиотечные классы? Вы их будете использовать из вне или же вместе с библиотечными методами? Т.е. передавать инстансы этих классов в качестве параметров?

Answer (score 2):

### Вариант 1

Если я правильно понял, то Вам могут помочь интерфейсы:

Есть **абстрактный класс:**

```
public abstract class Abstr {
    public abstract void  method();
}
```

И есть **интерфейс:**, в котором можно создать метод с дефолтной реализацией и методы, которые необходимо реализовать.

```
public interface Interface {
    //Поле, которое будет присутствовать во всех имплементациях
    public int field = 0;
    //"Пустой" метод который необходимо определить в имплементации 
    public void anotherMethod();
    //Метод с реализацией по умолчанию, будет доступен в имплементации
    default int retInt(){
         return 5;
    };
}
```

**Реализации:**

```
public class RealizationAbstr extends Abstr implements Interface {
    @Override
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("Hello from first Realization");
    }

    @Override
    public void anotherMethod() {
        System.out.println(1);
    }
}

public class RealizationAbstr2 extends Abstr implements Interface {
    @Override
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("Hello from second Realization");
    }

    @Override
    public void anotherMethod() {
        System.out.println(2);
    }
}
```

Однако при таком подходе существует ограничение - поля интерфейсов по сути ***константы*** и их изменить нет возможности.

### Вариант 2

Еще одним вариантом может быть "встраивание" промежуточного класса.
То есть перейти от такой модели Наследования :

```
Abstract <- 3x(Realization)
```

К такой:

```
Abstract <- AbstractWithFieldsAndMethods <-3x(Realization)
```

Способ простой и подходит, если вы можете редактировать классы реализующие абстрактный класс.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться [дефаултными реализациями методов интерфейса](//docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html).

Делаешь наследника и указываешь у него интерфейс, содержащий дефаултную реализацию:

```
class Base { 
    public int functionFromBase() { 
        return 0;
    }
}

class A extends Base {
    public int functionFromA() { 
        return 1;
    }
}

class B extends Base {
    public int functionFromB() { 
        return 2;
    }
}

interface Common {
    default int functionFromCommon() {
        return 7;
    }
}

class AA extends A implements Common {}
class BB extends B implements Common {}
```

```
AA a = new AA();
BB b = new BB();

System.out.println(a.functionFromBase()   + " " + b.functionFromBase()  );
System.out.println(a.functionFromA()      + " " + b.functionFromB()     );
System.out.println(a.functionFromCommon() + " " + b.functionFromCommon());
```

Полный пример: http://ideone.com/9adriG

PS: В C# аналогичную роль выполняют методы-расширения. В некоторых других языках (например, js) может использоваться понятие миксинов (mixins).

Comment: @sanek-zhitnik Однако при таком подходе существует ограничение - поля интерфейсов по сути константы и их изменить нет возможности.К сожалению Общие поля нужны не static.